# Copy range from sheet overwrites data

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to copy a range from multiple sheets (within the same workbook) to a column in a new sheet in the workbook. I would like values in the range ("C2:C12021") from the first sheet to be copied to column A in the new sheet, then values in the range ("C2:C12021") from the second sheet to column B in the new sheet and so on.

I am currently using the following code however the macro keeps copying the range from each of the sheets I am trying to combine to the same column of the sheet where I am trying to combine them.

As such only the range from the last sheet appears in the combined sheet, I presume this is where the range copied from the other sheets has simply been overwritten as the macro loops through the sheets.

```
Sub CombineWorksheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MergeSheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a worksheet named "MergeSheet"
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "MergeSheet"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        'Copy target range
        Set CopyRng = sh.Range("C2:C12021")

         CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the horizontal values of cells as integers, i.e.

```
.Cells(Vertical As Integer, Horizontal As Integer)
```

So at the start of the loop, have a counter variable, and use that in the horizontal value.

```
Dim count As Integer
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        count = count + 1

        'Copy target range
        Set CopyRng = sh.Range("C2:C12021")

        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(last + 1, count)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

    End If
Next
```

Comment: You were faster :) I also find it strange if author want to merge data, why every sheet is going to be pasted one row below (`last +1`)? Maybe just leave it `1`?